# I want to get the selected item using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

html code

```
<div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl as vm">
  <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.model" 
     ng-change="vm.userSelect(data.model)"
     ng-click="vm.loadTenantList()">
    <option ng-repeat="tenant in vm.tenants" >{{tenant.name}}</option>
  </select><br>
</div>
```

js code

```
$lmsapp.controller('DropdownCtrl',['tenantServices','dialogService',function (tenantServices,dialogService,$log){
var vm = this;
vm.tenants=[];

vm.loadTenantList=function(){
    tenantServices.tenantList({},function(response){
        vm.tenants=response.dataList;
    });
};

vm.data = {
    availableOptions: [
        vm.loadTenantList()
      ]
   };
}]);
```

how can I get the selected element?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rather use ng-options:

```
    <div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl as vm">
      <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="vm.selectedTenant" ng-init="vm.loadTenantList()" 
ng-options="tenant as tenant.name for tenant in vm.tenants "> 
      </select>
    </div>
```

`vm.selectedTenant` will give you selected tenant.

Comment: should i do smth at the controller

Comment: No need to do any thing at controller may be you can initlize vm.selectedTenant ={}, but that will not make any difference.

Comment: and how can i make it as a default param using $http

Comment: Do you want it preselected ?? Try this in your method:vm.loadTenantList=function(){
    tenantServices.tenantList({},function(response){
        vm.tenants=response.dataList; vm.selectedTenant = vm.tenants[0]
    });
};

Comment: no when the user clicks on one of them i will set it up as a default parameter using $http services.                                                                           This is what school does to you

Answer (score 0):

you can get like this keep the id in the select option tag like below

```
<select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.model" 
   ng-change="vm.userSelect(data.model)"
    ng-click="vm.loadTenantList()"  id="TenaList">
    <option ng-repeat="tenant in vm.tenants" >{{tenant.name}}</option>
</select>
```

In your script

```
var e = document.getElementById("TenaList");
var selected_value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl as vm">
   <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="vm.data" 
      ng-click="vm.loadTenantList()">
     <option ng-repeat="tenant in vm.tenants" >{{tenant.name}}</option>
   </select><br>
</div>
```

then you can get the selected item using `vm.data`